# AntiforgeryToken validation failed

Tags: authentication, antiforgerytoken, asp.net-core-2.1

I've ASP CORE 2.1 application that works in conjunction with angular SPA client.
I protected my application as stated [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1343/aspnet-core-csrf-antiforgery-token).

But the problem is that I constantly receive 400 Bad Request right after I login to the system. As per my point of view that is what happened in the system:

1. First request to the app -> returns AntiForgery CookieToken and
   RequestToken (**important note that user isn't authenticated yet**)
2. User logins to the system -> AntiForgery validation passed,
   authentication cookies sent to the client.
3. User requests any
   other endpoint, but since the AntiforgeryTokenSet was issued for
   non-authenticated user, he gets 400 Bad Request.

It is obvious, that after login we need to reissue AntiforgeryTokenSet but I've no idea where and how. I've tried to issue token in the Result Filter but with no luck.

```
public class SPAAntiforgeryCookieResultFilter : ResultFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly IAntiforgery _antiforgery;

        public SPAAntiforgeryCookieResultFilter(IAntiforgery antiforgery)
        {
            _antiforgery = antiforgery;
        }

        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
        {
            Action assignAntiForgery = () =>
            {
                var tokens = _antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context.HttpContext);
                context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
            };

            if (context.Result is ViewResult)
            {
                assignAntiForgery();
            }
            else if (string.Equals(context.ActionDescriptor.ActionName, nameof(AccountController.Login), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                assignAntiForgery();
            }
        }
    }
```

It seems that ResultExecutingContext does't know about authenticated user and issues token still for anonymous user.
So, how we can refresh antiforgery RequestToken token right after login for authenticated user?

Answer (score 0):

For now I find out the way how to get around the issue.

Previously, I returned `Ok()` after successful login, but now I do `RedirectToAction()` and my `OnResultExecuting` filter was slightly changed in order to refresh token after `RedirectToAction` happend.

```
    public class SPAAntiforgeryCookieResultFilter : ResultFilterAttribute
        {
            private readonly IAntiforgery _antiforgery;

            public SPAAntiforgeryCookieResultFilter(IAntiforgery antiforgery)
            {
                _antiforgery = antiforgery;
            }

            public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
            {
                Action assignAntiForgery = () =>
                {
                    var tokens = _antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context.HttpContext);
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
                };

                if (context.Result is ViewResult)
                {
                    assignAntiForgery();
                }
                // Here we check whether our redirect action is executed. Update AFT if it is
                else if (string.Equals(context.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["action"], nameof(AccountController.RefreshAntiForgeryAfterLogin), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    assignAntiForgery();
                }
            }
        }
```

This dirty hack works in the next way:

1. First request to the app -> returns AntiForgery CookieToken and RequestToken (important note that user isn't authenticated yet)
2. User press login to the system -> AntiForgery validation passed, authentication cookies set up -> User get response with authentication cookies and status code 302 (redirect) -> User reach out our `RedirectUserToAction` method with **context that has authentication info** (`User.IsAuthenticated == true`)